# tocloft newlistof numwidth

Tags: tocloft

I'm trying to make a custom `List of TBDs` similar to the built-in `List of Figures` and `List of Tables`. I got that all to work using `tocloft`'s `newlistof` feature, but the numbering format I'm using for TBDs (`TBD-#`) is longer than the default `numspacing` on the table. There are plenty of questions on here for how to adjust that spacing, and the documentation seems to describe how to do it, but for some reason I can't get it to work in my environment. Here are three methods I've tried (where my `newlistof` is called `TBDs`):

1. `\setlength{\cftTBDsnumwidth}{10em}`
2. `\renewcommand*\cftTBDsnumwidth{10em}`
3. `\cftsetindents{TBDs}{0mm}{10em}`

Here's a MWE (also [live on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pxsdgfkfwthx)):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listTBDname}{List of TBDs}
\newlistof{TBDs}{tbd}{\listTBDname}

% Theoretically, any of these options should fix the problem.
\cftsetindents{TBDs}{0mm}{10em}
\setlength{\cftTBDsnumwidth}{10em}
\renewcommand*\cftTBDsnumwidth{10em}

\newcommand{\TBD}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{TBDs}%
    [TBD-\arabic{TBDs}: #1]%
    \addcontentsline{tbd}{figure}{%
        \protect\numberline{TBD-\arabic{TBDs}}#1%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\listofTBDs

\clearpage
\section{A section}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent

\clearpage
\section{A section}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image: Tex Rendering Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Since my `addcontentsline` is using the `figure` type, I had to do:

```tex
\setlength\cftfignumwidth{10em}
```

Unfortunately, since my real document also uses Table of Figures, this solution causes another problem. I guess I need to figure out how to make a custom `<type`> there instead. When I put something new there, the resulting table loses a lot of formatting...

---

Edit: I found the solution that avoids re-defining the formatting for `listoffigures`. Here's an updated MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listTBDname}{List of TBDs}
\newlistof{TBDs}{tbd}{\listTBDname}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\l@tbd}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5em}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\TBD}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{TBDs}%
    [TBD-\arabic{TBDs}: #1]%
    \addcontentsline{tbd}{tbd}{%
        \protect\numberline{TBD-\arabic{TBDs}}#1%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofTBDs

\clearpage
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}\caption{Some figure}\end{figure}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\begin{figure}\caption{Some figure}\end{figure}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\begin{figure}\caption{Some figure}\end{figure}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent

\clearpage
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}\caption{Some figure}\end{figure}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\begin{figure}\caption{Some figure}\end{figure}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent
\begin{figure}\caption{Some figure}\end{figure}
\TBD{Some definition}\par\noindent

\end{document}
```

And here's how it looks:

[image: list of figures and TBDs]

Comment: Well done. Peter W.